# Typescript: how to name array of strings that could be undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm using Typescript in my React Native app and I define the following array:

```
const arr: string[] = Platform.select({
  ios: ["a", "b", "c"],
  android: ["a", "b", "c"]
})
```

VsCode underlines `arr` and tells me `Type 'string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string[]'`, so I changed it to

```
const arr: string[] | undefined = Platform.select({
  ios: ["a", "b", "c"],
  android: ["a", "b", "c"]
})
```

VsCode removes the underline on `arr` in the definition, but when I use it in my code it underlines it there and says `Argument of type 'string[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'`

I think the problem is that `Platform.select()` might return `undefined`, but then I'm using `arr` in my code for operations that require it to have type `string[]` instead of `string[]`. How can I modify my code to remove all these warnings?

Answer (score 1):

You can give an empty array as the default value when `Platform.select` returns `undefined` using [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

This would also work

```
const arr: string[] = Platform.select({
  ios: ["a", "b", "c"],
  android: ["a", "b", "c"]
}) ?? []
```

Answer (score -1):

This may suffice:

```js
const arr: string[] = Platform.select({
  ios: ["a", "b", "c"],
  android: ["a", "b", "c"]
}) as unknown as string[]
```

But, I would be cautious. It's usually better to listen to Typescript and adjust your design accordingly.

Comment: There's better alternatives (like the one Amila posted) that don't circumvent typechecking.

Comment: I would have thought that would fall under "adjusting your design."

Comment: It does, I just disagree that a pattern like this should be encouraged, regardless of whether there's a warning.